# better performance for jquery $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using select2 plugin (http://select2.github.io/select2/)

This searches through all  option values for the $selectstring variable and then selects the ones found. If its searching over 200 option values it takes about 5-6 seconds...im trying to reduce this.

Is there a way to speed up my search element for containing-string code?

Is it true that using a for loop instead of $.each would be better performance?

jquery:

```
$('#selectbutton').click(function() {
    var selectstring = $('#selectstring').val();

    if (!selectstring.trim())
        return false;

    stringVal.push($('#projadd\\[\\]').val());

    $('#projadd\\[\\]').find('option').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':contains(' + selectstring + ')')){
                  stringVal.push($(this).val());
        }
        $('#projadd\\[\\]').val(stringVal).trigger("change");
    });
    $('#selectstring').val('');
});
```

Comment: could you explain more on what this attempting to do?

Comment: @DanielA.White I edited my post with more info

Comment: What are the backslashes doing in your selector strings? And why are you putting an array into `.val()`? Looks like you are trying to add to a string, but that is not what `.push()` does. There is a lot wrong with your code.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Passing an array to `.val()` on a multi select mean it will select multiple options : http://jsfiddle.net/cunr5u2t/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is not the `.each()` but your code in general. You are creating a lot of jQuery object when there is no need to it. You are also assigning a value to an element multiple times in the each when it should be outside of it.

Try avoiding jQuery when you can easily do it vanilla. Also try avoiding `:contain` since it is a costly selector.

Go with a code that look like that :

```
$('#selectbutton').click(function() {
    var selectstring = document.getElementById('selectstring').value; //Reduced the number of function call and doesn't create a jQuery object.

    if (!selectstring.trim())
        return false;

    var $projadd = $('#projadd\\[\\]');//You use it more than 1 time? Cache it

    stringVal.push($projadd.val());

    $projadd.find('option').each(function(){
        if(this.textContent.indexOf(selectstring) > -1){ //Don't use :contains, use native Javascript methods
                  stringVal.push(this.value); //Do not create jQuery object, acces value property. Accessing properties is always faster than calling a function.
        }
    });

    $projadd.val(stringVal).trigger("change"); //Move it out of the .each, you only need to set the value once.
    document.getElementById('selectstring').value = ''; //Same reason as above.
});
```

Comment: WOW what a difference! Thank you for explaining better code uses, i am still new and learning. much appreciated.

Comment: @rubberchicken you're welcome, there is probably more possible optimisation, but I think it's a good start.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all try reducing the numbers of object fetching calls inside the loop.**

then the baseline is this:

`For loop` is faster.

You may get at least 40% better performance using `for loop` with assigning values inside the loop.

Please see these online tests : http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75

Note: If you care about performance, first create a model of your `script` then test it in various conditions using some framework, [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) for eg.

[image]

Comment: Language-level loops are faster, but even `$.each` doesn't really matter in OPs case - sacrificing readability for minimal perfomance boosts is a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting that the native `.forEach()` is significantly worse than `jQuery.each()`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that using a for loop instead of $.each would be better performance?

Yes, but it's small part of time spent in your loop.

> Is there a way to speed up my search element for containing-string code?

Yes, you can use searching in element textContent without jQuery.

```
   $('#projadd\\[\\]').find('option').each(function(){
            if(this.textContent.indexOf(selectstring) !== -1){
                      stringVal.push($(this).val());
            }
            $('#projadd\\[\\]').val(stringVal).trigger("change");
    });
```

Anyway, this code is quite buggy because eg. `.val(stringVal)` sets element value to array (is it intended? I don't think so).